# Performance Analytics drawdown function not working r

Tags: r, performanceanalytics

I am trying to plot a drawdown graph of daily profits using the Performance Analytics package. I have managed to do this with the code:

```
cols = rainbow(ncol(pdrawdown),s=0.7, v=0.8, alpha= 0.7)
chart.Drawdown(pdrawdown, legend.loc = "bottomleft",colorset = cols,
               main = "Drawdown Chart", xlab ="Date", ylab = "Drawdown")
```

for percentage returns. However when I use profits (which deals with much larger numbers), the graphics window doesn't even show any table, and no error or warning messages are produced.

My pdrawdown data is structured like so:

```
structure(list(Arbitrage = c(-410344.36040002, 43186613.0914002, 
-56243745.8289002, 33212085.9369, 2685633.86650004, 52056396.8137002
), Cmdty = c(-5661740.59000004, -12816611.3327999, -15271367.5797001, 
30328698.7996001, 2346206.95040001, -20111667.3121), Cnvt = c(-0.448500000005879, 
-4.09389999999985, -3.76900000000023, -4.46530000000348, 9.47310000000289, 
5.57809999999154), FI = c(-4959851.92789985, 51301719.2496983, 
19347533.8012021, -45928596.3382014, -126566982.481699, 7039919.16710053
), IndexArb = c(465514.007300064, 712460.314099789, -1241298.64239982, 
859103.288600107, -9142.46960010222, 1670160.15220016), OptVolD = c(3207463.8402, 
-2645827.2004, 1917467.1194, -1645717.199, 1346643.9976, 1249267.9222
), OptVolG = c(1809178.81009999, -1247076.75579998, 1208738.92329999, 
-998966.340099988, 474978.958799993, 2312496.41480001), Other = c(3121114.45319998, 
-7558428.4574, 28751941.5262, -8287057.41060003, -5057308.97439997, 
25541692.1845), RVG = c(107064420.2606, 41122417.5658004, -33634242.2959002, 
-25318480.7920002, -9396822.53510034, 69874891.7186005), SAAsia = c(-31022426.4966, 
-1381533.43030003, 21484053.8479001, 15456037.1175, 11307323.7993999, 
8081090.74740009)), .Names = c("Arbitrage", "Cmdty", "Cnvt", 
"FI", "IndexArb", "OptVolD", "OptVolG", "Other", "RVG", "SAAsia"
), row.names = c("2015-08-03", "2015-08-04", "2015-08-05", "2015-08-06", 
"2015-08-07", "2015-08-10"), class = "data.frame")
```

Update: Setting a ylim value i.e.

```
cols = rainbow(ncol(pdrawdown),s=0.7, v=0.8, alpha= 0.7)
chart.Drawdown(pdrawdown, legend.loc = "bottomleft",colorset = cols,
               main = "Drawdown Chart", xlab ="Date", ylab = "Drawdown",ylim = c(-1,0))
```

causes the graph to appear but it still displays effectively nonsensical data, no matter what my lower bound is for the ylim. With returns, however, this ylim term works as expected, fixing the axes of the plot.

Answer (score 0):

Since no-one was able to give an answer, I will post my best solution in case anyone else runs into this problem in the future.

As far as I can tell, the issue is (as expected) simply being caused because the drawdown PnL is too large. My "hack" to fix this was to divide the datatable by a number that causes all values to be below 1. In my case this meant my y scale being in billions like so:

```
pdrawdown = pdrawdown/1000000000 # PnL displays in billions (set units here)

cols = rainbow(ncol(pdrawdown),s=0.7, v=0.8, alpha= 0.7)
chart.Drawdown(pdrawdown, legend.loc = "bottomleft",colorset = cols, 
               main = "Drawdown Chart", xlab ="Date", ylab = "Drawdown ($billions)
```

Dividing by any number smaller just gave a very odd looking graph with massive jumps that did not resemble the returns graph for the same data.

I suspect this is because the drawdown graph is designed for percentages and thus can only deal with numbers between 0 and -1 (maximum drawdown in percentage being, of course, -100%).